# python3 urllib hanging on stats.nba

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

i'm trying to get gameday statistic from stats.nba.com, fox example from this url http://stats.nba.com/stats/scoreboard/?GameDate=4/2/2017&LeagueID=00&DayOffset=0

Here is my code:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

base_url = 'http://stats.nba.com/stats/scoreboard/?GameDate=4/2/2017&LeagueID=00&DayOffset=0'
headers = {'user-agent': ('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) '
                              'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                              'Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36'),
               'referer': 'http://stats.nba.com/scores/'}
req = Request(base_url, headers = headers)   

content = urlopen(req).read()
print(content)
```

And it's do nothing. If i change base_url on any other url this code works fine. What am i doing wrong?

I know about requests module but i cant use it in my project.